# Integration on Left and Right Hand Side

Tags: integration

> Let $f$ be a non-negative function defined on the interval $[0,1]$. If $$\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1-(f'(t))^2}dt=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$$ and $f(0)=0$, $x\in[0,1]$. Prove that $f\Big(\dfrac{1}{2}\Big)<\dfrac{1}{2}$, $f\Big(\dfrac{1}{3}\Big)<\dfrac{1}{3}$

For this type of problem where equality is used and $f'(t)$ or $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ is inside $\sqrt{}$, I am struggling with this type of problem.[image: Function]

Comment: non-negative function!

Comment: I presume that non negative function means value $\in$ [0,$\infty$)

Comment: My mean is the typo at first line.

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi can you check the edit okay now?

Comment: @MANMAID thanks for editing this question

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi Your assumptions in problem are not match together and clearly conflict each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1-(f'(t))^2}\,\mathrm dt=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm dt$$
$$\begin{equation}1-f'^2=f^2\label{1}\tag{1}\end{equation}$$
$$-2f'f''=2ff'$$
By $(1)$, it is impossible (since $f(0)=0$) that $f'=0$, thus,
$$f''+f=0$$
Giving
$$f(x)=A\sin{x}+B\cos{x}$$
By the initial condition, $B=0$, and again by $(1)$,
$$1-A^2\cos^2{x}=A^2\sin^2{x}$$
$$A^2=1$$
As $f$ is non-negative on $[0,1]$, $A=1$. Hence, $f(x)=\sin x$.

And as $x\ge\sin{x}$ on $[0,\infty)$ and $x=\sin{x}\iff x=0$ (you could show it by differentiation, by graph, or by series expansion, etc.), it shows that $f(x)<x$, $f(1/2)<1/2$, $f(1/3)<1/3$.

---

*Proposition: $x\ge\sin x$ for $x\ge 0$, equality holds if and only if $x=0$.*

**Proof**
We shall show that $g(x):=x-\sin x\ge 0$.

As we have $g(0)=0$ and $g'(x)=1-\cos x\ge 0$ (as $\cos$ varies from $-1$ to $1$), 
$$x-\sin x=\int_0^x 1-\cos t\,\mathrm dt \ge 0$$
And also as $g$ is increasing in $[0,\infty)$ and already has a zero at $0$, $g(x)=0, x\in [0,\infty)\iff x=0$.
As desired. $\square$

---

***Answer to the original miscopied question***

Assuming $f$ is real, by differentiating the original equation and squaring both sides
$$\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+(f'(t))^2}\,\mathrm dt=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm dt$$
$$1+f'(x)^2=f(x)^2$$
Let $x=0$,
$$f'(0)^2=-1$$
A contradiction. So, $f$ does not exist.

---

*Original proof*
$$\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+(f'(t))^2}\,\mathrm dt=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm dt$$
Differentiate and square both sides,
$$1+f'^2=f^2$$
Differentiate again,
$$2f'f''=2ff'$$
Now, we have either
$$f'=0$$
or
$$f=f''$$
For the former, taking the initial condition of $f(0)=0$, apparently $f\equiv 0$, for the latter, we have
$$f(x)=C_1e^x+C_2e^{-x}$$
Recall that 
$$1+f'^2=f^2$$
We have
$$1=4C_1C_2$$
This shows that the signs of $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the same, but as $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ are always positive, $f$ should have no zero, which contradicts the initial condition.

Thus, $f\equiv 0$, but again , if we put it in
$$1+f'^2=f^2$$ 
It shows $1=0$, which is also a contradiction.

So, such $f$ does not exist.

Comment: Again, I believe that there exists a nice geometric approach.

Comment: After contradiction $1+f'^2=f^2$ implies $f=1$.!

Comment: Apperently! With differentiatial equation we have $f(x)=\cosh(x+C)$ and doesn't satisfy $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @BAI I cross checked it and found the question is correct, it is asked in a Competitive examination.

Comment: @BAI Added the original question, Answer is "C"

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi **In your picture, it says $\sqrt{1-f'(x)^2}$ instead of $\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$**

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi The answer to the question in the picture is given at the top of my answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you can deduce from $-2f'f''=2ff'$ that necessarily $f''+f=0$ by invoking the fact that $f' \neq 0$. It seems to me that you should be allowed to do that only if $f'(x) \neq 0$ for **any** value of $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @JeanMarie well... I just use the fact that it is impossible that $f'(x)=0$ for all value of $x\in [0,1]$ (i.e. If so, then $f$ is constant, then the initial condition gives that $f$ is $0$ everywhere in the interval, $(1)$ then gives a contradiction for all value of $x$ in the interval.), and use the assumption that $f$ is differentiable. But, under this particular case, it's true that we could prove the required without the assumption on differentiability since $0<1/3<1/2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I mean that in an equation involving functions say in the form $\phi \times f=\psi \times f$, you cannot simplify by $f$ unless $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$.